# How can I insert same element into an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of objects. But when I insert the object the I previously added, it will override my previous object. how can I solve it?

I have on object called player. In player, I have two array : one called onHandWeapon, one called onFieldWeapon. They are array of weapon object.

```
function player(lp){
        this.lp = lp;
        this.onFieldWeapon = new Array();
        this.onHandWeapon = new Array();

    } 

function weapon(id, heart, bullet, src){
            this.id = id;
            this.heart = heart;
            this.bullet = bullet;
            this.src = src;
            this.location;
            this.name;
            this.discription;
            this.bufferBullet = bullet;
    }
```

I have set three dummy object in onHandWeapon array. Then I want to randomly pick up one of them and put it into onFieldWeapon and assign a random location to it.

```
 function aiCreateWeapon(){
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*ai.onHandWeapon.length);
        $('#console').append(' ' + b + ' ');
        var ip = 100;

        while($('#'+ip).attr('class') != 'enemyField'){
            ip = Math.floor(Math.random()*48);
        }

        encurrentWeapon = ai.onHandWeapon[b];

        var source = encurrentWeapon.src;

        var oImg = document.createElement("img");
        oImg.setAttribute('src', source);
        oImg.setAttribute('height', '60px');
        oImg.setAttribute('width', '60px');
        $('#'+ip).append(oImg).show('explode','slow');

        encurrentWeapon.location = ip;  
        ai.onFieldWeapon.push( encurrentWeapon);

        $('#console').append(' ' + ai.onFieldWeapon[0].location + ' ');
}
```

aiCreateWeapon is a function bind to a button. When I click it, the ai.onFieldWeapon[0].location is a fixed location until it changes. I have check that every time when the object which is same as the first element, is added to the onFieldWeapon Array, it will override the first element's data.

Comment: Please post your code, your question makes little sense without it.

Comment: It is difficult to understand without seeing the code. But I think you probably using the same index to keep the object. Better to take backup of array and then add new object to it and then copy that backup to your original array.

Comment: encurrentWeapon is a global variable

Comment: I think the problem is that var sports = ["soccer", "baseball"]; when there is soccer in the array I can't push another soccer into it, can I? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

you should use splice

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.write("Added: " + fruits.splice(2,0,"Lemon") + "<br />");
document.write(fruits);

</script>

Added:
Banana,Orange,Lemon,Apple,Mango
```

Comment: [Don't use](http://w3fools.com) w3schools as reference. Not only is it not related to the w3c but we also have proper references like MDN to use instead. Also, your example uses document.write (eeew!)

Comment: its an example from w3schools.

Comment: What @missingno is trying to say is that w3schools is not a great resource. In fact, much of their information is incorrect and their popularity is largely due to their long history on the web and commanding score in search engine indexes. [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org) is a much better resource to link to.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: you should check the link in my comment. It explains things in long form

Comment: @missingno I know this site..... the guy asked for banana and all this comments gave him elephant....:) I know there are better sites then w3scholls......

Answer (score 0):

This is how you [add an element to an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). This way nothing will be overwritten:

```
var sports = ["soccer", "baseball"];
sports.push("football", "swimming");
```